# Concatenate a varying number of list columns in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a big data frame of 12 columns. Each row has a list of values. How to concat all values stored in a row of lists? Here is a snippet of my actual data frame.

**My Dataframe**

```
index       data1        data2
0        [1,2,3,4]       [3,0,-7]
1        [-1,2]         [9,10,-7]
2        [1,2,3,4,9]       [3,0,-7]
3        [4,6,3]       [3,1,8]
```

I would like to find concatenate these columns into a single one. This is so I can then find the max of each list.

**My Code**

```
max_val =  max(max(map(lambda x: x[-1], df[['data1','data2']].values)))

for i,x in df.iterrows(): 
    print(x[[data1],['data2']])
```

**Current output at last iteration**

```
data1    [4,6,3]       
data2    [3,1,8]
```

**Expected output at last iteration**

```
[4,6,3,3,1,8]
```

How to concatenate row lists as a single list?

Comment: Are all the lists the same size? _I would like to find maximum in whole dataframe_ Maximum what? This seems like a strange use case for a DataFrame, can you provide some more context?

Comment: Phew, your question really needed some detailing. Please keep details cogent, and you should focus on the problem you're trying to solve, rather than asking how to do what you think is the solution to that problem. In this case I've edited your question to reflect the former because I don't want to retroactively change my answer, but I hope you get the point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried concatenating the columns directly?

```
df
                 data1        data2
index                              
0         [1, 2, 3, 4]   [3, 0, -7]
1              [-1, 2]  [9, 10, -7]
2      [1, 2, 3, 4, 9]   [3, 0, -7]
3            [4, 6, 3]    [3, 1, 8]

df['data1'] + df['data2']            

0       [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 0, -7]
1           [-1, 2, 9, 10, -7]
2    [1, 2, 3, 4, 9, 3, 0, -7]
3           [4, 6, 3, 3, 1, 8]
```

For multiple columns:

```
df.sum(axis=1).to_frame('result')     
# to select specific columns, use
# df[['data1', 'data2', ...]].sum(axis=1).to_frame('result')  

                          result
index                           
0         [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 0, -7]
1             [-1, 2, 9, 10, -7]
2      [1, 2, 3, 4, 9, 3, 0, -7]
3             [4, 6, 3, 3, 1, 8]
```

---

***Bonus***
to find the max, just call `max` on each list via `map` (don't convert to a frame before calling `map` as it is only defined on Series):

```
df.sum(axis=1).map(max)  

index
0     4
1    10
2     9
3     8
dtype: int64
```

Comment: The problem is I have 12 columns. Some times I need to combine 8 or 4 or 12 columns data. so it is not the same number.

Comment: This should be reflected in the question. It seems like an important restriction in the solution

Comment: @CeliusStingher Yes! I agree on that part. I edited my equestion. Thanks

Comment: Nailed it. Thanks.